# How to select only specific hours from big table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select only specific hours from my table that contain "Datetime" and other variables.

**Example 1**:

```
select distinct(Datetime) from NWP_OUT where HOUR(Datetime) = '00';
```

this works but when i try to select not only '00' no luck and no result

**Example 2:**

```
select distinct(Datetime) from NWP_OUT where HOUR(Datetime) = '00' and '06';
```

only show the first

I tried using 'between' but then i got 02,04,and 05

My end goal is to select only the data for hours: '00,03,06,09,12,18,21'
it is 10 years of data so manual selection will be hard.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(datetime)
FROM NWP_OUT
WHERE HOUR(datetime) IN (0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21)
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much. Worked perfectly. Kind Regards - M.Slavchev

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `IN`

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(Datetime)
FROM
  NWP_OUT 
WHERE 
  HOUR(Datetime) IN ('00','03','06','09','12','18','21')
```

Comment: Ty so much! that worked nicely! it was bugging me for 2 days! Kind Regards